# Is it possible to add database connection automatically in database.php

Tags: laravel

I want to add database connection by automatically.
Example
when user click some button. System will create a new database, and user can switch to use that new database.
I have no problem to create a new database automatic but problem is I have to edit database.php file manually every time.

database.php

```
.
.
.
.
'connections' => [

    'this_is_added_automatically_1' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => env('host'),
        'port' => env('port'),
        'database' => env('database'),
        'username' => env('username'),
        'password' => env('password'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'schema' => 'public',
        'sslmode' => 'prefer',
    ],
    
    'this_is_added_automatically_2' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => env('host'),
        'port' => env('port'),
        'database' => env('database'),
        'username' => env('username'),
        'password' => env('password'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'schema' => 'public',
        'sslmode' => 'prefer',
    ],
    .
    .
    .
    .
    . and more
        
],
```

I switch database by

```
$users = DB::connection('connection_name')->select(...);
```

Comment: Why do you need to allow users to create a database?

Comment: this is only example